# Dividing in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, integer-division

I´m trying to do the select function of the image below, but the result for "perc_vol_lei" is zero, that is incorrect.

```
select to_char (tb_esq.datahora, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as data_esq, tb_esq.tick, tb_esq.variacao, tb_esq.quantidade as qtt_26, tb_dir.quantidade as qtt_0,
     (tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade) as volume_no_leilao,
     ((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantidade) as perc_vol_lei  

from tb_registros as tb_esq 
     join tb_registros as tb_dir on tb_esq.tick = tb_dir.tick 
        and to_char(tb_esq.datahora,'yyyy-mm-dd') = to_char(tb_dir.datahora,'yyyy-mm-dd')
    
        where (tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade) > 50000 and tb_esq.refer =26 and tb_dir.refer = 0 
                AND tb_esq.tick <>'DOLFUTV' and tb_esq.tick <>'IBOV' and tb_esq.tick <>'WDOFUT'and tb_esq.tick <>'DOLFUT'
order by volume_no_leilao desc`
```

Anyone can help me?

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: It's `INTEGER` division. You need to cast your values to `DOUBLE PRECISION` or `NUMERIC`.  Ex: `<your_value>::DOUBLE PRECISION`

Comment: @JSpratt a FLOAT? Are you sure you want all the problems related to a float? That's almost a random result...

Comment: Yeah... I'll remove that actually.

Comment: JSpratt, @FrankHeikens it´s not working yet.

I tried with the following three options: 
first: ((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantidade):: double precision as perc_vol_lei   /  

second: round(((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantidade):: decimal, 5) as perc_vol_lei   /  

third: ((tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantidade):: numeric as perc_vol_lei.

And the result are the same.

I still needing help.

Comment: Seems you need to force numeric operations not just cast the result. Perhaps: `(tb_esq.quantidade - tb_dir.quantidade)/tb_esq.quantida::numeric)`.

Comment: It works Belayer, thank you so much!

The ")" was in the wrong place.